# Do we have BBM for Windows devices (HTC 8X)?

Tags: apps

Can we Install BBM for Windows devices also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BlackBerry Messenger is only available for BlackBerry, iOS and Android devices http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry_Messenger

Comment: ...at the moment